# Update permission when user field changes in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django admin site, I can set the "is_active" field of a user. Is there anyway to automatically grant certain permissions to the user once I set his "is_active = True"?

Comment: What do you mean by automatically...?

Comment: In other words, I would like to associate the field of the user with certain permissions. If is_active = True, the user gets those permissions and if is_active = False, the user lose those permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `post_save` Django Signal on the User model, which runs after the `User.save()` is done, so in your case you want to test for `instance.is_active`, while you're you can also revoke the permissions in the signal if the user is set as `is_active = False`

This is also better than overriding some admin interface, because the `post_save` will run after the model save, regardless if done from admin panel or elsehwere

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save